# Perl6: comparison operator ~~

Tags: operators, raku

I don't understand this behavior:

```
> sort([1,2,3,4]) ~~ sort([1,2,3,4])
False
```

Can you please explain it to me?
Why these two lists (that are obviously equal) are not equal according to Perl 6.

**Update**

Interesting, but it depends on Perl6 version (I've just noticed it):

```
$ which perl6
/usr/bin/perl6
$ dpkg -S `which perl6`
rakudo: /usr/bin/perl6
$ perl6 --version
This is perl6 version 2015.11 built on MoarVM version 2015.11
$ perl6
> sort([1,2,3]) ~~ sort([1,2,3])
True
> 
$ export PATH=~/.rakudobrew/bin:$PATH
$ perl6 --version
This is Rakudo version 2017.12 built on MoarVM version 2017.12.1
implementing Perl 6.c.
$ perl6
To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
> sort([1,2,3]) ~~ sort([1,2,3])
False
>
```

From a discussion on #perl6:

```
[19:35] <+committable6> AlexDaniel, 
¦2015.12,2016.01.1,2016.02,2016.03,2016.04,2016.05,2016.06,2016.07.1,2016.08.1,2016.09,2016.10,2016.11,2016.12: «True␤» 
¦2017.01,2017.02,2017.03,2017.04.3,2017.05,2017.06,2017.07,2017.08,2017.09,2017.10,2017.11,2017.12,2018.01,HEAD(8afd791): «False␤»
```

Versions that return True (line 1) and False (line 2).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key observation is that `sort` doesn't actually return a list:

```
> sort([1,2,3,4]).^name
Seq
```

The [documentation for sort](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/sort) seems to be out of date :(. I'll try to fix that soon.

So, a [Seq](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Seq) is a sequence, basically an iterator that you can also try to use like a list.

But, in its default mode, when you iterate a `Seq`, it doesn't store the old elements, mostly to enable code like

```
for $filehandle.lines -> $line {
    # do something with $line here
}
```

to not leak memory. (This is comparable to python's iterators.)

So, that's probably why nobody implemented `Seq.ACCEPTS` (the smart match operator `~~` calls `ACCEPTS` on the right argument) to behave as you would expect in this case, as that might be a destructive operation. So the default `ACCEPTS` behavior kicks in, which does an identity comparison, and returns `False`.

If you change your code to

```
> sort([1,2,3,4]) ~~ sort([1,2,3,4]).list
True
```

it behaves the way you want it to.

I'll discuss with the other Perl 6 developers if `Seq.ACCEPTS` could be changed to behave more sensibly.

Comment: Docs updated in https://github.com/perl6/doc/commit/f74384849d754ed550cfe335a332546be19770ec

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Interesting, but it depends on implementation: see my update.  So you just can't be sure what ~~ returns

Comment: @IgorChubin "you just can't be sure what ~~ returns" Ouch. Moritz's suggestion to `.list` the result of a `sort` is presumably an appropriate work around. But, still, ouch. I don't know of a blog post or whatever that explains how P6 approaches changes to the language; and to roast; and to Rakudo. Perhaps someone will write one that also explains how this aspect of 2017.01 was conceived, considered and applied; what was right about the change; what was wrong; etc.

Comment: @raiph  *"Perhaps someone will write"*. Challenge accepted! :) See: https://rakudo.party/post/Perl6-On-Specs-Versioning-Changes-And-Breakage

Answer (score 7):

The literals you wrote are `Array`s:

```
say WHAT [1,2,3,4] ; # (Array)
```

Plain `Array`s are eagerly evaluated, so their contents are known at all times. So the `~~` operator yields `True` when applied to `Array`s with identical types and contents:

```
say [1,2,3,4] ~~ [1,2,3,4] ; # True
```

But you are applying a function, so you must pay attention to what that function returns.

The [`sort` function](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/sort) returns a [`Seq`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Seq), a sequence, which is a fundamentally different type.

`Seq`s are lazily evaluated, so their contents are not computed until they have been completely iterated, exhausting them. It would not make sense to run through two `Seq`s to see if they equivalent because then they'd be exhausted.

So two `Seq`s whose elements would turn out to be identical are not themselves identical:

```
say Seq.new([1,2,3,4].iterator) ~~ Seq.new([1,2,3,4].iterator) ; # False
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! And see my update. The things are even more interesting

Comment: @IgorChubin I think my answer is redundant given Moritz's answer. Do you agree?

Comment: Please don't remove it anyway. Your answer is also useful

Comment: @raiph Please, don't remove your answer.